# Operators as callback functions in Swift

Tags: swift, callback, operators

In Swift, operators are declared as functions. Does it mean they can also be used as callback functions? If so, how? If not, why?

Idea is, depending on the values of two different numbers, apply different operators to them.

Comment: yes, they can be used as callback. but they do not make much sense as callback since you cannot provide custom code to be run, assume you pass (+) as callback, that will not doing much for you as the caller.

Comment: Why it doesn't make sense? You provide the values the operator operates on when calling the callback function. Those values might be variables, and you can provide different operators depending on what values you have to operate on.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift functions are *first class types*, you can pass them as arguments to other functions expecting them.

A callback is nothing more than a parameter of another function.

Putting this all together means that **yes**, you can use an operator as a callback, as long as its type is compatible.

For example you can do:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(0, combine: +)
// => 10
```

That is possible because `+` has type `(Int, Int) -> Int`, which matches the expected type for the `combine:` parameter of `reduce` when called on an array of `Int`.

Another example:

```
func foo(a: Int, f: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int {
  return { a, f in
    return f(a, 42)
  }
}

foo(1, -)
// => 41
```